# Webpack: 2 Outputs for 1 entry?

Tags: webpack

I am new to webpack. I want to output the same file 2 times, one normal bundle (file.js) and the same one with a hash in the name (file.12345.js). Something like this:

```
├── file.js
├── dist/ 
│   └── file.js
│   └── file.12345.js
```

However, as far as I understod you can only define 1 output in the config file. This is not working, because webpack requires a string as filename:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: ['./[name].js', './[name].[chunkhash].js']
}
```

How can I output both?

---

**Why do I want this / what is the problem?** 
I am hosting my code on heroku. On staging I want file.js, on production file.12345.js. However, promoting staging to production is **no extra build** on heroku - it simply copies the code. Running another script for it is not possible.

---

**Why not always use file.12345.js?** 
Of course I could also use a plugin for just inputting the latest file.12345.js into my html document. However, I do not have access to the html, since we are using a tool for building the website.

Comment: I don't think it's supported, and I can't really see a good use for it.
Are you sure it's not just an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: You can easily configure a build step to duplicate the file with the hash and strip it away in some other way.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post and stated the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

With webpack, you can return an array of configurations. So in your case, you can do this:

```
function createConfig(fileName) {
 return {
   output: {
      filename
   }
   // all other props
 }
}

module.exports = [
   createConfig('./[name].js'),
   createConfig('./[name].[chunkhash].js')
]
```

So what we do here, is to create a function, that returns a webpack config. The filename is passed as a param. So the filename can be set dynamically.

We export an array of webpack configs, that are created by calling the createConfig function. As a param, we pass in the filename we want.

One downside is, that with each config you return, everything is transpiled again. (So it takes twice as long for everything).

**Solution 2**

Use the copy-webpack-plugin to copy (rename) your file

- https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin

So for example, let webpack create the file.js for you and add the copy-webpack-plugin to your config like this:

```
plugins: [
   new CopyWebpackPlugin([
   {
      from: './dist/file.js'
      to: './dist/[name].[hash].[ext]',
      toType: 'template'
   }
  ], options)
]
```

Comment: Thank you! Solution 1 did the trick. I tried it with the plugin, but the plugin would run before the build is finished, so it would use the old file.js in the dist folder. Also placeholders wouldn't work because of this, it would just output "[name].js" etc.